# Hard time in Labplot! Does anyone have the same issue?

Tags: r

I currently am using a linux distribution called DAT Linux. I use it basically for data analysis using R and Python. However, i struggle with the Labplot 2.10.1

Specifically, i can't access neither the Python nor the R notebook option. I thought it was due to my system, but i tried on windows 11 and have the same issue.

Is anyone using labplot having the same issue, if yes is there a way to circumvent this ???

Thanks for your help

Session info --- Linux (x86_64) release 6.5.0-26-generic (DAT Linux)

I should be able to access the notebook menu and open a notebook either in python or R

Comment: it seems likely that this is not a problem with R (or python) but instead a problem with the OS and/or setup of LabPlot. For that, StackOverflow is likely not the best place to ask the question, consider [unix.se] or superuser.com or a forum specific to https://labplot.kde.org. (I have never heard of LabPlot, so beyond that I think I cannot provide much more help.)